# Windows Azure Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I have this problem on my windows azure visual studio whenever I want to login, I will get this error message.

"Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again."

I have entered the user details 101% correctly, I am using login control.

Here is my web.config details.

I have set my NETWORK SERVICES to full permission I does no work too.

Please help me I have been stuck here for days

Please View my code here as I can't paste it here. Thanks

http://pastebin.com/gX0qAHdQ

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type=""/>
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="User" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true" >
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
          name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i cannot see any connection string to your Azure Database.

Comment: @KrunalPatil hello, i set up this project using cloud >azure. hmmm how do i set connecting string to my Azure Database (aspnetdb.mdf).

Comment: Do you need your application to connect to an azure database that you have already created? Are you using the azure website option or have you deployed on a virtual machine?